# Proper terminology for Object... args

Tags: java, methods, args

I'm working in Java and the typical way you specify multiple args for a method is:

```
public static void someMethod(String[] args)
```

But, I've seen another way a few times, even in the standard Java library. I don't know how to refer to this in conversation, and googling is not of much help due to the characters being used.

```
public static void someMethod(Object... args)
```

I know this allows you to string a bunch or arguments into a method without knowing ahead of time exactly how many there might be, such as:

```
someMethod(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, ... etc
```

How do you refer to this type of method signature setup? I think it's great and convenient and want to explain it to some others, but am at a lack of how to refer to this. Thank you.

Comment: See [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This way to express arguments is called *varargs*, and was introduced in Java 5.
You can read more about them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html).

Comment: Looks like C/C++ main functions

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik ? in C/C++ main function is either `main( void )` or `main( int argc, char *argv[] )` ... not quite the same... unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 8):

As a Keppil and Steve Benett pointed out that this java feature is called varargs.

If I'm not mistaken, Joshua Bloch mentioned that there is a performance hit for using varargs and recommends telescoping and using the varargs method as a catch all sink.

```
public static void someMethod(Object arg) {
    // Do something
}

public static void someMethod(Object arg1, Object arg2) {
    // Do something
}

public static void someMethod(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {
    // Do something
}

public static void someMethod(Object ... args) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: +1 great addition to this conversation. I think this is the link from Jashua Bloch: http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-42-use-varargs-judiciously.html

Makes sense, and this seems to be a good way to go about the varags with performance in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The Parameter method(Object... args) is called `varargs`. Try this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).