# Combine observables based on obserable

Tags: android, rx-java

#### The structure:

The                 `api.vehicles()` endpoint returns a list of ids. The `api.driveState(int id)` returns a state for a vehicle with the id as parameter.

#### What I need:

Make a call to the `.vehicles()`. For the returned ids, make a call per id on the `.driveState(id)` endpoint and wait for all the calls to succeed and return a list of states together. Let's ignore the `retrys()` and network failures for now.

#### What I have tried is:

```
api.vehicles()
    .flatMap(vehicles -> merge(getVehicleStates(vehicles)))
    .toList()
    .doOnNext(driveStates -> {

    });
```

where getVehicleStates() is:

```
private List<Observable<DriveState>> getVehicleStates(List<Vehicle> vehicles){
    List<Observable<DriveState>> states = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
        states.add(api.driveState(vehicle.getId()));
    }
    return states;
}
```

What would have been better I believe is the .zip() function. However I do not know how to deal with the FuncN() method:

```
api.vehicles()
        .flatMap(vehicles -> 
                zip(getVehicleStates(vehicles), new FuncN<DriveState>() {
                    @Override public DriveState call(Object... args) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
        ));
```

---

PS: slightly similar but unanswered:
[Combining 'n' Observables of the same type (RxJava)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131429/combining-n-observables-of-the-same-type-rxjava)

Comment: `zip` sure looks like it's what you're after. You're just having trouble dealing with FuncN? What trouble?

Comment: If it's the first time you've seen varargs, [check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674023/proper-terminology-for-object-args) :)

Comment: @AdamS Well the problem is that the varargs are of `Object` class and not of the specified `DriveState`.

Comment: Yeah, you can do a for each and cast it.

Answer (score 0):

The `zip(Iterable, FuncN)` operator will zip your observables, and supply the results of all of them in the `Object.. args`.

It looks like you're looking for a list of all `DriveState` - this is what you've got in `args`. The [documentation for varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) explains that this is, effectively, an array of `Object`, whose construction is conveniently hidden by the `...` syntax.

You can use `zip` to get a list of all the `DriveState` as follows:

```
zip(getVehicleStates(vehicles), new FuncN<List<DriveState>>() {
    @Override public List<DriveState> call(Object... args) {
        return Arrays.asList((DriveState[])args);
    }
}
```

Of course, you might want to operate on the `DriveState` objects and return some modification to them or some result object etc instead of the list.